# Using Python/Pandas to compare columns of unequal length

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

https://ibb.co/cyCzVgy

I would like to be able to compare the `NEW_PRICE` to the `LINE_TOTAL_ALLOWED` amounts based on the `PROC_CODE`. So ideally, Pandas will start on row 1, match the `PROC_CODE` and `PROC_CODE_NEW`, and then subtract `NEW_PRICE` from `LINE_TOTAL_ALLOWED` and spit out the difference in a new column `PRICE_DIFFERENCE`.

I get this error in Python:

```
" raise ValueError(ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of 
  index (920776)"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far that is giving me the above error:

```
for value in df[['PROC_CODE', 'LINE_TOTAL_ALLOWED']].items():
    df['price_difference'] = np.where(df['LINE_TOTAL_ALLOWED'] == ((df['NEW_PRICE'])*15)), 0,  df['LINE_TOTAL_ALLOWED'] - ((df['NEW_PRICE'])*15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, you can map all values you don't yet have row-wise like 1 `PROC_CODE` and 1 `PROC_CODE_NEW` to each row in your `df` as a prior step and then you can do your calculation.

E.g.:

```
df = df.merge(df_other['PROC_CODE', 'PROC_CODE_NEW'], left_on='key_column_name', right_on='key_column_name')
```

Then you can fill the new value by e.g. applying a [lambda function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and assigning the result to a new column:

```
def your_logic(row):
    # Assign new price based on row['PROC_CODE'], ...    

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: your_logic(x), axis=1)
```

Your image link is broken.

Please provide a minimal example, so an exact code answer will be possible, because like this it is difficult to understand the format your data comes in.